# Alter DatacardValue with Slider and vice versa in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps

I would like to have a interlocked Slider and DatacardValue, so that if the user changes the value in one of them, the other will be altered for the same value in response.

Making this an one-way affair was simple enough by setting the Dafault property in the DatacardValue to the Slider value, but no matter how I try to make changing the DatacardValue also change the Slider, I aways get a circular reference error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my question here:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-PowerApps-Formerly/How-can-I-connect-text-input-box-to-slider-control/m-p/83389#M32142

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try setting a [variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-variables) that both controls reference and set

Comment: Thanks Filip, that's pretty much what the link I posted below says.